# multiple preg_replace, don't replace replaced

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have this example input:

```
text with magazine and sp
```

and i have to find "magazine" and "sp" and enclose them in a "span" tag like this output:

```
text with <span class="highlight">magazine</span> and <span class="highlight">sp</span>
```

this is my function :

```
 function highlight($text, $phrase, $options = array()) {
if (empty($phrase)) {
 return $text;
}

$default = array(
 'format' => '<span class="highlight">\1</span>',
 'html' => false
);
$options = array_merge($default, $options);
extract($options);

if (is_array($phrase)) {
 $replace = array();
 $with = array();

 foreach ($phrase as $key => $segment) {
    $segment = "($segment)";
    if ($html) {
     $segment = "(?![^<]+>)$segment(?![^<]+>)";
    }

    $with[] = (is_array($format)) ? $format[$key] : $format;
    $replace[] = "|$segment|iu";
 }

 return preg_replace($replace, $with, $text);
} else {
 $phrase = "($phrase)";
 if ($html) {
    $phrase = "(?![^<]+>)$phrase(?![^<]+>)";
 }

 return preg_replace("|$phrase|iu", $format, $text);
}
}
```

but with this code i get this on output:

```
text with <<span class="highlight">sp</span>an class="highlight">magazine<!--<span class="highlight"-->span> and <span class="highlight">sp</span>
```

there is a way for don't replace the "sp" of "< span >"?

Comment: I assume `$phrase` is an array with the values "magazine" and "sp"?

Comment: Combining all the segments in one single regex (calling `preg_replace` only once) might solve your problem.

Comment: #jwatts1980: yes, $phrase = array('magazine', 'sp');
#Julian: i'm not so good with regex, i will search how i have to do and i will try, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
function highlight($text, $phrase, $options = array(), $lol = false) {
    $b = preg_replace("/".implode('|', $phrase)."\b/", "<span class=\"highlight\">$0</span>", $text);
    return $b;
}
```

thanks to #Julian